# How to make LinearLayout's X axis move under my finger?

Tags: android, touch, android-linearlayout, gesture

I need to know what i can do to make a `LinearLayout` move together with my finger but i want to move only the X axis and not the Y.

And after finished moving, when you "finger up" the `LinearLayout` back to original X position.

How i can do this?

Comment: scrollTo(), scrollBy()

Comment: scroll methods are not only for `ScrollView`'s ?

Comment: no, they are View's methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assume ll is the name of your linear layout:

```
    ll.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        float lastX;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            View item = v;

            switch(event.getAction())
            {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                lastX = event.getX();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                item.scrollBy((int) (event.getX()-lastX), 0);
                lastX = event.getX();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                item.scrollTo(0, 0);

            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: You just saved my life :) you are great.

Comment: Just a thing: I can revert the values? because i just noticed that is reversed, i move finger left it goes right and i move finger right it moves left.. '-'

Comment: and how i do that ? =p

Comment: Did it, you only need a "-" negativing the value of "(event.getX()-lastX)" now it works properly, i edited the answer.